# How to convert a DTO to Domain Objects

Tags: domain-driven-design, dto

I'm trying to apply ubiquitous language to my domain objects.

I want to convert a `Data Transfer Object` coming from a client into the domain object. The `Aggregate's Constructor` only accepts the required fields, and the rest of parameters should be passed using `aggregate's` `API` even when the `Aggregate` is being created(by say `CreateAggregate` `command`).

But the `DTO` to `Aggregate` mapping code becomes a bit messy:

```
if(DTO.RegistrantType == 0){
    registrantType  = RegistrantType.Person()
}
elseif(DTO.RegistrantType == 1){
    registrantType  = RegistrantType.Company()
}
//.....
//.....
var aggregate = new Aggregate(
        title,
        weight,
        registrantType,
        route,
        callNumber,
    )

//look at this one:

if(DTO.connectionType == 0){
    aggregate.Route(ConnectionType.InCity(cityId))
}
elseif(DTO.connectionType == 1){
    aggregate.Route(ConnectionType.Intercity(DTO.originCityId,DTO.DestinationCityId)
}
//..........
//..........
```

One thing I should mention is that this problem doesn't seem a domain specific problem.

How can I reduce these If-Else statements without letting my `domain internals leakage`, and with being sure that the **aggregate(not a mapping tool)** doesn't accept values that can invalide it's business rules, and with having the ubiquitous language applied?

Please don't tell me I can use `AoutoMapper` to do the trick. Please read the last part carefully.'

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A typical answer would be to convert the `DTO` (which is effectively a message) into a `Command`, where the command has all of the arguments expressed as domain specific value types.

```
void doX(DTO dto) {
    Command command = toCommand(dto)
    doX(command)
}

void doX(Command command) {
    // ...
    aggregate.Route(command.connectionType)
}
```

It's fairly common for the `toCommand` logic use something like a `Builder` pattern to improve the readability of the code.

```
if(DTO.connectionType == 0){
    aggregate.Route(ConnectionType.InCity(cityId))
}
elseif(DTO.connectionType == 1){
    aggregate.Route(ConnectionType.Intercity(DTO.originCityId,DTO.DestinationCityId)
}
```

In cases like this one, the strategy pattern can help

```
ConnectionTypeFactory f = getConnectionFactory(DTO.connectionType)
ConnectionType connectionType = f.create(DTO)
```

Once that you recognize that ConnectionTypeFactory is a thing, you can think about building lookup tables to choose the right one.

```
Map<ConnectionType, ConnectionTypeFactory> lookup = /* ... */

ConnectionTypeFactory f = lookup(DTO.connectionType);
if (null == f) {
    f = defaultConnectionFactory;
}
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect but you know `RegistrantType.Person()` returns enum value of 0 and `RegistrantType.Company()` returns enum value of 1 in this specific case. The reason I didn't pass the number into the aggregate was to avoid leaking the domain's internals. And if I create a factory in this specific case the factory should again return a number as enum flag.And that sounds like an implicit and anemic model to me.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

So why don't you use more inheritance

for example

```
class CompanyRegistration : Registration {

}

class PersonRegistraiton : Registration {

}
```

then you can use inheritance instead of your if/else scenario's

```
public class Aggregate {
  public Aggregate (CompanyRegistration) {
     registantType = RegistrantType.Company();      
  }

  public Aggregate (PersonRegistration p) {
     registrantType = RegistrantType.Person(); 
  }


}
```

you can apply simmilar logic for say a setRoute method or any other large if/else situations.

Also, i know you don't want to hear it, you can write your own mapper (inside the aggegate) that maps and validates it's business logic

for example this idea comes from fluentmapper

```
var mapper = new FluentMapper.ThatMaps<Aggregate>().From<DTO>()
                    .ThatSets(x => x.title).When(x => x != null).From(x => x.title)
```

It isn't too hard to write your own mapper that allow this kind of rules and validates your properties. And i think it will improve readability